# Spring Integration tcp reply MessageTimeoutException

Tags: tcp, spring-integration

I'm using spring integration to interface with a company that listens for a tcp connection.
I use a TcpOutboundGateway to send the message and put the ack on the reply channel.
This works pretty well.
However, I periodically and sometimes consistently get the MessageTimeoutException while waiting for my 3rd party to send the Ack. In their logs they complain that the socket connection was closed before they could send the ack. It seems to occur very quickly even though I've tried to specify they have up to 10 seconds to send the ack.

I've set the remotetimeout, requesttimeout, sendtimeout, soTimeout, but it seems like nothing much is helping to reduce the occurance.

I'm trying to run multiple of these gateways, don't think that's a problem.

I don't know enough to know what I should be looking for.

I believe this is the relevant bit of code:

```
@Bean
public TcpNetClientConnectionFactory createTcpClientConnectionFactory() {
  TcpNetClientConnectionFactory tcpNetClientConnectionFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
  LisSerializer lisSerializer = new LisSerializer(maxMessageSize);
  tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setSerializer(lisSerializer);
  tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setDeserializer(lisSerializer);
  tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(true);
  tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setSoTimeout(tcpTimeout);
  return tcpNetClientConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="tcpToLisEncoded")
public TcpOutboundGateway createTcpOutboundGateway(TcpNetClientConnectionFactory createTcpClientConnectionFactory){
  TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
  tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(createTcpClientConnectionFactory);
  tcpOutboundGateway.setReplyChannel(tcpOutAck());
  tcpOutboundGateway.setRemoteTimeout(tcpTimeout);
  tcpOutboundGateway.setRequestTimeout(tcpTimeout);
  tcpOutboundGateway.setSendTimeout(tcpTimeout);
  tcpOutboundGateway.setRequiresReply(true);
  return tcpOutboundGateway;
}
```

Error I get:

```
    018-02-22 22:56:44.969 ERROR 29 --- [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway          : Tcp Gateway exception

org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for response
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:146) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) [spring-messaging-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) [spring-messaging-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) [spring-messaging-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:360) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:271) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:188) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) [spring-messaging-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:150) [spring-messaging-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) [spring-messaging-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:42) [spring-messaging-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:38) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:79) [spring-messaging-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:70) [spring-messaging-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:449) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:422) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:478) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:433) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:424) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.java:65) [spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.sendMessage(Unknown Source) [na:na]
```

Comment: Try also to use `tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setSoKeepAlive(true)` also. And it's also not clear for me why do you use `setSingleUse(true)`?..

Comment: I'll give keepAlive(true) a go.
I set singleuse because I have 3 servers processing messages. My desire is that when one gets a message it delivers it and then gives up the connection so the others connect if they have something to process.

Comment: Fraid keepAlive resulted in the same behavior.